# How to improve perfomance on query NOT IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, notin

I have the following SQL Query.

```
SELECT em.employeeid, tsi.timestamp
FROM timesheet_temp_import tsi
JOIN employee emp ON emp.employeeid = tsi.credentialnumber
WHERE
tsi.masterentity = 'MASTER' AND
tsi.timestamp NOT IN
(
    SELECT ea.timestamp 
    FROM employee_attendance ea 
    WHERE 
    ea.employeeid = em.employeeid
    AND ea.timestamp =  tsi.timestamp
    AND ea.ismanual = 0
)
GROUP BY em.employeeid, tsi.timestamp
```

This query compares a import table (with employee time and attendance timestamps).

Sometimes `timesheet_temp_import` has more than 95,000 rows and my query has to show **only** the timestamps that are **new** for the employee. If the timestamp already exists for an employee then I have to exclude it.

The query is working but is taking more than 4 minutes so I want to know if I can improve the `NOT IN` statement with other that can help me to reduce this time.

Comment: For questions about query performance, please specify the table structure and indexes too, and an indication of the amount of data in those tables.

Comment: Can you restrict the main `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause to get only the latest entries in `timesheet_temp_import`? You could use some kind of bookmark...

Answer (score 6):

Using `NOT EXISTS` might help you.

```
SELECT 
    em.employeeid,
    tsi.timestamp
    FROM timesheet_temp_import tsi
    join employee emp ON emp.employeeid = tsi.credentialnumber
    WHERE
    tsi.masterentity = 'MASTER' AND

    NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT NULL  
        FROM employee_attendance ea 
        WHERE 
        ea.employeeid = em.employeeid
        AND ea.timestamp =  tsi.timestamp
        AND ea.ismanual = 0
    )
    GROUP BY 
    em.employeeid,
    tsi.timestamp
```

Comment: @LucM Could you explain why this should be used instead of a `LEFT JOIN` and checking if the column is null?

Comment: @JohnOdom [not in vs not exists vs left join](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Answer (score 3):

You have this query:

```
SELECT em.employeeid, tsi.timestamp
FROM timesheet_temp_import tsi JOIN
     employee emp
     ON emp.employeeid = tsi.credentialnumber
WHERE tsi.masterentity = 'MASTER' AND
      tsi.timestamp NOT IN (SELECT ea.timestamp 
                            FROM employee_attendance ea 
                            WHERE ea.employeeid = em.employeeid AND
                                  ea.timestamp =  tsi.timestamp AND
                                  ea.ismanual = 0
                           )
GROUP BY em.employeeid, tsi.timestamp;
```

Before rewriting the query (as opposed to reformatting it;), I would check the indexes and logic.  Is the `GROUP BY` necessary?  That is, are there duplicates produced by the outer query?  My guess is no, but I don't know your data.

Second, you want indexes.  I think the following indexes:  `timesheet_temp_import(masterentity, credentialnumber, timestamp)`, `employee(employeeid)`, `employee_attendance(employeeid, timestamp, ismanual)`.

Third, I would ask if you even have time sheets for non-employees.  I think you can get rid of the outer `join`.  So, this might be the query that you want:

```
SELECT tsi.credentialnumber as employeeid, tsi.timestamp
FROM timesheet_temp_import tsi
WHERE tsi.masterentity = 'MASTER' AND
      tsi.timestamp NOT IN (SELECT ea.timestamp 
                            FROM employee_attendance ea 
                            WHERE ea.employeeid = tsi.credentialnumber AND
                                  ea.timestamp =  tsi.timestamp AND
                                  ea.ismanual = 0
                           );
```

You might also get a marginal improvement by replacing the `NOT IN` with `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `except`

```
select whatever
from wherever
where somefield in 
(select all potential values of that field
except
select the values you want to exlude)
```

This is logically equivalent to `not in`, but faster.

Answer (score 2):

try this and I thin you mean emp

```
SELECT distinct tsi.credentialnumber, tsi.timestamp
  FROM timesheet_temp_import tsi
  JOIN employee emp 
    ON emp.employeeid = tsi.credentialnumber
   and tsi.masterentity = 'MASTER' 
  left join employee_attendance ea 
    on ea.employeeid = emp.employeeid
   AND ea.timestamp = tsi.timestamp
   AND ea.ismanual = 0
 where ea.employeeid is null
```

depending on indexs this may be faster

```
SELECT distinct tsi.credentialnumber, tsi.timestamp
  FROM timesheet_temp_import tsi
  JOIN employee emp 
    ON emp.employeeid = tsi.credentialnumber
   and tsi.masterentity = 'MASTER' 
  left join employee_attendance ea 
    on ea.employeeid = tsi.credentialnumber
   AND ea.timestamp = tsi.timestamp
   AND ea.ismanual = 0
 where ea.employeeid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE` clause for filtering instead of `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT 
    em.employeeid,
    tsi.timestamp
    FROM timesheet_temp_import tsi
    join employee emp ON emp.employeeid = tsi.credentialnumber
    left join 
    (
        SELECT ea.timestamp 
        FROM employee_attendance ea 
        WHERE 
        ea.employeeid = em.employeeid
        AND ea.timestamp =  tsi.timestamp
        AND ea.ismanual = 0
    ) t on t.timestamp = tsi.timestamp
    WHERE
    tsi.masterentity = 'MASTER' AND
    t.timestamp is null
    GROUP BY 
    em.employeeid,
    tsi.timestamp
```

Comment: @Blam you can't correlate the conditions with outside tables with a LEFT JOIN